# how to embed view controllers

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers that I want to embed. HomeContoller.swift and TabBar.swift. The TabBar.swift contains a reference to my story board because in the home controller.swift I made the interface programmatically. But in the story board I made The tab bar. I want to have my tab bar at the bottom of my screen at the same time my Home screen is showing. please help.

Answer (score 0):

It' all about identifier, you can set identifier in tabbar which view controller you want first.

Comment: soo I don't need to add any more lines of code just go to my Identifier?

Comment: I'm trying to get two view controllers to show at the same time my home view controller and tab bar controller are separate source files